# Как средствами WinAPI добавить ярлык приложения на панель задач?

Tags: c++, winapi

Собственно ярлык успешно пишется в папку `%appdata%\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Quick Launch\\User Pinned\\TaskBar\\file.lnk` средствами `IShellLink`,
но на панели задач его не видно. Какие действия нужно выполнить, чтобы он там появился?

Нашёл интерфейс `ITaskbarList` и его метод `AddTab(HWND)`, но программа вылетает с ошибкой при таком вызове:

```
ITaskbarList *TB;
TB->AddTab(HWindow);
```

Пытался повесить на панель задач запущенный установщик для теста. Но вообще надо, чтобы на панели появлялся один из файлов, который этот установщик распаковывает, то есть надо как то получить HWND исполняемого файла, который запускать до завершения установки не желательно. Это вообще реально?

Comment: Насколько мне помнится, юзер сам должен приклеить его туда, API нет (а то все программы будут туда добавляться наплевав на желание юзера).

Comment: Но как-то же установщики это делают? Даже чекбоксы есть типа "Значок на панели задач"

Comment: @VladD, так они ж и добавляются ;)

Comment: Полагаю, надо ещё какое-то уведомление заброадкастить, чтоб проводник перечитал параметры. После выхода из системы и повторного входа ярлык появляется, или нет?

Comment: Зачем выход из системы? Я в реестре смотрел - там без изменений. Просто когда установка доходит до создания кнопки в панели задач, установщик крашится.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать через `ShellExecute`, при помощи операции `taskbarpin`.

```
ShellExecute(NULL, L"taskbarpin", L"path/to/shortcut.lnk", NULL, NULL, 0);
```

Однако это убрали в Win10.